# How to select the oldest day, from a column type TEXT in Android SQLITE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am working with android and SQLITE Database. There I have to Limit the maximum number of records as 10 in one table. That table has a column`(dateReg)` to insert the date and time when the record is inserted. I am inserting records in to that column in the following format.(dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss)

I am trying to find the oldest record by the date and to update that record if the row count is 10.

Like to know whether there is a way to select the oldest day by a SQL query, to update that record if the total number of records are 10 in that table.

Thank you very much and Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks...!

Comment: why on earth would you be storing dates as text in such a useless format, again?

Comment: HI njzk2. If I store in any other type in SQLITE, is there a way that I can write a query and find the MIN Date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store dates in SQLite using columns with INTEGER datatype. To store them, use the `Date` or `Calendar` classes in Java to convert your date to Unix Format, and then simply order by this column. It's easier.

Comment: Hi thanks Tiago. But according to this post http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html, We don't have long type in SQLITE in Android. Also if we have to figure out in application side then why have to store specially in long type?

Comment: Sorry, it's the INTEGER datatype that you should use, as you can see here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Comment: Also, you don't need to order the data in application side. Since you are storing them using Unix Format, you have a number representing your date, then just order them in your query using your date (which has an INTEGER datatype) column.

Comment: `INTEGER` is "1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes" which means it is anything between `byte` and `long` depending on what needs to be stored.

Comment: inserting the current unix timestamp also works if you just insert `strftime('%s','now')` as value (does not work via ContentValues). That's even faster than computing it in java. [SQLite - Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: @zapl you are correct, but SQLite3 actually recommends you to use integers to store dates in Unix Format

Comment: @zapl Also, I'm not telling you to compute this in Java. Just calculate your time when you will insert your data in your database. After that, you can order them using a select query, as in "SELECT columns FROM table ORDER BY your_integer_column_that_stores_datetime"

Comment: @TiagoPasqualini yes, I just meant that a SQLite `INTEGER` is not the same as a Java `int`. It's a `long` based on the maximum it can store. And that comment was actually @JibW

Answer (score 2):

There is a simplest way if you cannot change your database schema :

there is an id (_id, usually) which is autoincrement. the min(_id) is the oldest row, you can delete it and insert a new row.

Comment: If data is coming in with alway increasing time like let's say a conversation/chat this answer is very simple yet fast. If data is coming in with higher/lower timestamps not ordered this doesn't work at all.

Comment: @FrankKrumnow, yes, this is specific to this particular case. As per the question: "That table has a column(dateReg) to insert the date and time when the record is inserted."